# Does Terraform require all branches of a ternary conditional to exist before running the condition statement?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform version v0.11.13

I'm trying to use `"${var.create_roles ? aws_iam_role.lambda.arn : var.role}"` as the `role` parameter of the `aws_lambda_function` resource.

If `var.create_roles` is false the `aws_iam_role.lambda` resource doesn't get created.

I was hoping that the above ternary would work but it appears that `aws_iam_role.lambda.arn` has to evaluate because I get `module.lambda.aws_lambda_function.lambda_with_vpc: Resource 'aws_iam_role.lambda' not found for variable 'aws_iam_role.lambda.arn'` when `var.create_roles` is false

The `aws_iam_role` has the `count = "${var.create_roles ? 1 : 0}"` conditional.

Is there anyway to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

And I found the answer [Terraform 11 upgrade guide](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-11.html#referencing-attributes-from-resources-with-count-0)